# SQL Query for returning rows divided by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(money_deposit + bonus_deposit) as money_deposit_total,
SUM(money_withdraw + bonus_withdraw) as money_withdraw_total
FROM transactions 
where player_id = 1 and created_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-05' 
group by game_id;
```

What I want to do is to return the results by date, so instead of returning only 1 row, I want to return 1 row for each date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `GROUP BY game_id,created_date`

Comment: A row for each date of the `game_id`? Then add the date to your `group by`

Comment: "SELECT *" and "GROUP BY" ? How's that supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply add this

```
group by game_DATE;
```

At the end of your sql query

Comment: I dont think It will work with **Select *..** and **Group By**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
   (
      SELECT game_id,created_date,
      SUM(money_deposit + bonus_deposit) as money_deposit_total,
      SUM(money_withdraw + bonus_withdraw) as money_withdraw_total
      FROM transactions 
      where player_id = 1 and created_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-05' 
      group by game_id,game_DATE;
    ) AS T INNER JOIN transactions S ON S.game_id = T.game_id
```

Comment: If there is more than one transaction by game it will give a lot of duplicates. But it will work with, lets say, the game table.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the group by function for crated date column.

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(money_deposit + bonus_deposit) as money_deposit_total,
SUM(money_withdraw + bonus_withdraw) as money_withdraw_total
FROM transactions 
where player_id = 1 and created_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-05' 
group by game_id,created_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you remove the *. You can't show a transaction field that is not used in the group by without an aggregation function. One common trick is to use the MAX function if you know all the values are the same for a given date and game_id.

```
SELECT created_date
       ,game_id
       ,SUM(money_deposit + bonus_deposit) as money_deposit_total
       ,SUM(money_withdraw + bonus_withdraw) as money_withdraw_total
       ,Max( field_1) as field1
       ,Max( field_2) as field1
FROM transactions 
where player_id = 1 and created_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-05' 
group by game_id,
         created_date
```

Another alternative is to use subqueries in the select

```
SELECT created_date
       ,( Select game_name from game g where g.game_id = t.game_id) as name
       ,SUM(money_deposit + bonus_deposit) as money_deposit_total
       ,SUM(money_withdraw + bonus_withdraw) as money_withdraw_total
```

[...] or join afterwards

```
   SELECT *
      FROM ( SELECT created_date
           ,game_id
           ,SUM(money_deposit + bonus_deposit) as money_deposit_total
           ,SUM(money_withdraw + bonus_withdraw) as money_withdraw_total
           ,Max( field_1) as field1
           ,Max( field_2) as field1
    FROM transactions 
    where player_id = 1 and created_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-05' 
    group by game_id,
             created_date ) AUX
  JOIN game g ON g.gami_id = AUX.game_id
```